# C# SendKeys or InputManager but only send DownKey OR UpKey>

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I Have a program which where a button exist. When the button is pressed, it should simulate a key pressed. However, using `SendKeys` or `InputManager` only sends a specific key, but not a key press.

I want a method that when the button is pressed, it simulates a key down, and when released it sends a key up to the keyboard.

Comment: Provide more details like framework, library, technology which you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

Add `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);
    public static void PressKey(Keys key, bool up)
    {
        const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x1;
        const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;
        if (up)
        {
            keybd_event((byte)key, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, (UIntPtr)0);
        }
        else
        {
            keybd_event((byte)key, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, (UIntPtr)0);
        }
    }

    private void buttonUp_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        PressKey(Keys.Up, false);
    }

    private void buttonUp_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        PressKey(Keys.Up, true);
    }
```